# IMPORT CSV TO LARAVEL 9 Undefined array key 24

Tags: csv, laravel-9, read.csv, import-from-csv

i made import csv file to laravel. this is the contents of the CSV data that I will import :
[data csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grtdd.png)

when I try to import a CSV file whose contents are in the image I uploaded, which is empty/null, and I have added (Double) $row[24] ?? NULL to handle if the value is NULL then directly insert 0.0 in the table.[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Rfg.png)

data type 'lemhanor' and 'lemakpek' --> [data type lemhanor and lemakpek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JttGs.png)

whereas for 'lemhanor' and 'lemakpek' they have the same data type and in the CSV the values are both empty. What to do?

this is migration for absensi_table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('absensi', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_karyawan');
        $table->string('nik')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->date('tanggal');
        $table->string('shift');
        $table->time('jadwal_masuk');
        $table->time('jadwal_pulang');
        $table->time('jam_masuk');
        $table->time('jam_keluar')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->double('normal',2,1);
        $table->double('riil',2,1);
        $table->time('terlambat')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->time('plg_cepat')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('absent',5);
        $table->time('lembur')->nullable()->default(null);;
        $table->time('jml_jamkerja')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('pengecualian')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('hci',5)->default(True);
        $table->string('hco',5)->default(True);
        $table->string('id_departemen');
        $table->double('h_normal',2,1);
        $table->double('ap',2,1);
        $table->double('hl',2,1);
        $table->time('jam_kerja')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->double('lemhanor',2,1);
        $table->double('lemakpek',2,1);
        $table->double('lemhali',2,1);
       
        $table->foreign('id_karyawan')->references('id')->on('karyawan')->onDelete('cascade');
       
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

this is AttendanceImport.php in HTTP folder:

```
<?php
namespace App\Imports;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Absensi;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;

class AttendanceImport implements ToModel
{
public function startRow(): int
{
    return 2;
}

public function getCsvSettings(): array
{
    return [
        'delimiter' => ';'
    ];
}
/**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function model(array $row)
{
    if(isset($row[0]) && isset($row[2])) 
    {
        if(!Absensi::where('id_karyawan',$row[0])->where('tanggal',Carbon::parse($row[2])->format("Y-m-d"))->exists())
        {
            return new Absensi([
                'id_karyawan'   => $row[0],
                'nik'           => $row[1] ?? null,
                'tanggal'       => Carbon::parse($row[2])->format("Y-m-d"),
                'shift'         => $row[3] ?? null,
                'jadwal_masuk'  => $row[4] ?? null,
                'jadwal_pulang' => $row[5] ?? null,
                'jam_masuk'     => $row[6] ?? null,
                'jam_keluar'    => $row[7] ?? null,
                'normal'        => $row[8] ?? null,
                'riil'          => (Double) $row[9] ?? null,
                'terlambat'     => $row[10] ?? null,
                'plg_cepat'     => $row[11] ?? null,
                'absent'        => $row[12] ?? null,
                'lembur'        => $row[13] ?? null,
                'jml_jamkerja'  => $row[14] ?? null,
                'pengecualian'  => $row[15] ?? null,
                'hci'           => $row[16] ?? null,
                'hco'           => $row[17] ?? null,
                'id_departemen' => $row[18] ?? null,
                'h_normal'      => (Double) $row[19] ?? null,
                'ap'            => (Double) $row[20] ?? null,
                'hl'            => (Double) $row[21] ?? null,
                'jam_kerja'     => $row[22] ?? null,
                'lemhanor'      => (Double) $row[23] ?? null,
                'lemakpek'      => (Double) $row[24] ?? null,
                'lemhali'       => (Double) $row[25] ?? null,
            ]);

            // dd($row);
        }
        // else{
        //     Log::info('id karyawan dan tanggal absensi sudah ada');
        // }
    }
    // else{
    //     Log::info('Row 0  dan 2 kosong');
    // }
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function importcsv(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new AttendanceImport, request()->file('file'));
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Data Imported Successfully');
}
```

Comment: This kind of error is generally due to the input DATA, so you should provide a sample of the RAW content of your CSV file, not an image of it. BTW, a CSV is a text file that you can open with any text editor, you don't need Excel or the likes

Comment: this link to CSV File, but not all the data can be read there : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LcLWKhNGA3OKJNtjvYPmjPQ7FUcrIdxQ/view?usp=share_link